# Is there a way to pass prop to JSX.Component?

Tags: reactjs

I have below react code:

```
const MyComponent = <OptionsSelect
            options={[
              {
                text: 'Another Item'
              },
              {
                text: 'Bulk assessment'
              }
            ]}
          />

export default () => (
    <div> { MyComponent } </div>
)
```

The `MyComponent` itself is already a JSX component. Is there a way for me to pass in properties to it?

I know one way to do is to change `MyComponent` to a function which returns the JSX component so I can pass the properties as the function parameters as below code:

```
const MyComponent = () => <div />
```

But I am looking for a direct way to do that. Or is it even possible?

Comment: No, const MyComponent = (props) =>{ return () } but you can try this

Comment: why wont you use functional components in the first place? I think it is easier than spending a lot of time trying to find something else. Unless you're trying to achieve something? I'm curious..